# SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErro

Tags: java, xml, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to learn using of session in struts2. So, I just want to implement a Login/Logout, Profile application. I am following a basic tutorial available on internet. But, Its not at all working. Please help me with the following issue  How to fix it.

```
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/listener/TilesListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.listener.TilesListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    ... 17 more

Sep 19, 2015 5:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Login] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper warn
WARNING: Local DTD is missing for publicID: -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN - defined mappings: {-//Apache Struts//XWork 1.0//EN=xwork-1.0.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 1.1.1//EN=xwork-1.1.1.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.0//EN=xwork-2.0.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 1.1//EN=xwork-1.1.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.1//EN=xwork-2.1.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN=struts-2.0.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.1.3//EN=xwork-2.1.3.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN=struts-2.3.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN=struts-2.1.7.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN=struts-2.1.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.3//EN=xwork-2.3.dtd}
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ValidatorFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.UnknownHandlerFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.util.ContentTypeMatcher)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DispatcherErrorHandler)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.ExcludedPatternsChecker)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:13 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.AcceptedPatternsChecker)
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:15 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider register
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:15 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider register
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:15 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider register
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:15 PM org.apache.struts2.config.Settings getLocale
WARNING: Settings: Could not parse struts.locale setting, substituting default VM locale
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:16 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ObjectTypeDeterminerFactory <clinit>
INFO: Setting DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer as default ...
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 19, 2015 5:44:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10281 ms
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  </web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="abc" extends="struts-default">

<action name="login">
<result >login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="loginprocess" class="com.javatpoint.Login">
<result name="success"  >loginsuccess.jsp</result>
<result name="error" >loginerror.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="logout" class="com.javatpoint.Login" method="logout">
<result name="success" >logoutsuccess.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="profile" class="com.javatpoint.Profile">
<result name="success" >profilesuccess.jsp</result>
<result name="error" >profileerror.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>
</struts>
```

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676690/severe-error-configuring-application-listener-of-class-org-apache-struts2-tiles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `org.apache.tiles.listener.TilesListener` only available in the Tiles 2.0.3

In higher versions of Tiles the listener class is `org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener`.

[Download tiles-core-2.0.3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/t/Downloadtilescore203jar.htm)