# SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, xml

[image]I am trying to learn a basic Web-App in struts2. But, I am facing the following  issue. Please help me removing this probz.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:63)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.<init>(AbstractTilesListener.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener.<init>(TilesListener.java:38)
    at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener.<init>(StrutsTilesListener.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 20, 2015 12:17:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Login] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:28 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper warn
WARNING: Local DTD is missing for publicID: -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN - defined mappings: {-//Apache Struts//XWork 1.0//EN=xwork-1.0.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 1.1.1//EN=xwork-1.1.1.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.0//EN=xwork-2.0.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 1.1//EN=xwork-1.1.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.1//EN=xwork-2.1.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN=struts-2.0.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.1.3//EN=xwork-2.1.3.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN=struts-2.3.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN=struts-2.1.7.dtd, -//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN=struts-2.1.dtd, -//Apache Struts//XWork 2.3//EN=xwork-2.3.dtd}
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ConverterFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.InterceptorFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ValidatorFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.UnknownHandlerFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.util.ContentTypeMatcher)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DispatcherErrorHandler)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.ExcludedPatternsChecker)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:29 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.security.AcceptedPatternsChecker)
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider register
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider register
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider register
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM org.apache.struts2.config.Settings getLocale
WARNING: Settings: Could not parse struts.locale setting, substituting default VM locale
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ObjectTypeDeterminerFactory <clinit>
INFO: Setting DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer as default ...
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8899 ms
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/UITagsExample] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1c11080]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext[]] (value [[Lcom.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext;@226e75]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak. 
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Login]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/SimpleLogin_FirstPro_2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@136df08]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext[]] (value [[Lcom.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext;@16cbe3c]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak. 
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 20, 2015 12:17:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Here is my WEb.XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  </web-app>
```

STRUTS.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="abc" extends="struts-default">

<action name="login">
<result >login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="loginprocess" class="com.javatpoint.Login">
<result name="success"  >loginsuccess.jsp</result>
<result name="error" >loginerror.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="logout" class="com.javatpoint.Login" method="logout">
<result name="success" >logoutsuccess.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="profile" class="com.javatpoint.Profile">
<result name="success" >profilesuccess.jsp</result>
<result name="error" >profileerror.jsp</result>
</action>

</package>
</struts>
```

I am trying it to solve But, I am  unable to do so. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the log4j.jar in your classpath. Dowload the jar ad add it.

Comment: A log4j jar has been installed. You can see on that post

Comment: @Sourav I can not see the log4j.jar. I can only see log4j-over-slf4j.jar

Comment: @Sourav Also you show the buildbapth, not the classpath.

Comment: Okay!! Let me download and install that log4j jar.. Please wait

Comment: Thanks for your help . This error msg has gone away. But I am getting new errors :(

Comment: @Sourav Ad what is the error? It it helps, feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: extremely sorry!! this was a minute xml prob

Comment: SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/Initializable
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90147/discussion-between-sourav-and-jens).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Problem is solved. The problem was due to the version of Tiles-api.